# Prove or Disprove $x g(x) \geq f(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

Suppose f is an increasing real-valued function on $[0 , \infty)$ with $f(x) > 0,  \forall x$ and let $$g(x) = \frac 1x\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$$, $0 < x < \infty$ Then prove or disprove the following statement:

$xg(x) \geq f(0)$ for all $x \in (0 , \infty)$

My Attempt:

Since $f$ is increasing and $f(x) > 0$ , $\forall x \in [0 , \infty)$ so $t > 0$ in $[0 , \infty)$ $\implies$ f(t) > 0 $ \implies \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt > 0$ Therefore $\frac 1x\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt > 0$ for $x > 0$ $\implies g(x) > 0$ $\implies x g(x) > 0$ . Also $f(0) > 0$ as $f(x) > 0 , \forall x \in [0 , \infty)$ and $f$ is increasing. So $x g(x) \geq f(0)$ , $\forall x \in (0 , \infty)$. Am I right?

Comment: The statement is wrong, choose $f(x)=1$.

Comment: @MartinR: That's not an **increasing** function.

Comment: Of course it is. But you can modify the example slightly to make it *strictly* increasing, if necessary.

Comment: The statement must be wrong because $x g(x)
\to 0$ for $x \to 0$.

Comment: Oh, I agree the statement may be wrong. I suspect that the intended claim is just that $g(x) \ge f(0)$, because that says the average of an increasing function on an interval is greater than the value at the left end of the interval, which seems more true. :)

Comment: That's what I assume. In any case, the *argument* is wrong because $A > 0$ and $B> 0$ does not imply $A \ge B$.

Comment: @MeraBhai: Have you checked your conjecture with *any* function $f$? You should see immediately that the inequality does not hold.